# Flutter asset database error: The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I added my existing `database.db` file to my project with sqflite. No errors encountered, everything works fine, but... Flutter debug console says:

```
Restarted application in 772ms.
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<Countries>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<Countries>>#d0317):

The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<List<Countries>>
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _HomeScreen.buildBody.<anonymous closure>
#2      _FutureBuilderState.build
#3      StatefulElement.build
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (14052): Opening existing database
```

Here is my model `Country.dart`  :

```
class Countries {
  int countryId;
  String countryName;
  String countryImageURL;
  
  //Constructor
  Countries({this.countryId, this.countryName, this.countryImageURL});

  // Extract a Product Object from a Map Oject
  Countries.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    countryId = map['country_id'];
    countryName = map['country_name'];
    countryImageURL = map['image'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'country_name': countryName,
      'image': countryImageURL
    };
    return map;
  }
}
```

Here is my `database_helper.dart` file:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:city_travel_guide/model/Country.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class DbHelper {
  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    } else {
      _db = await initDb();
      return _db;
    }
  }

  initDb() async {
    var dbFolder = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(dbFolder, 'app.db');

    var exists = await databaseExists(path);

    if (!exists) {
      // Should happen only the first time you launch your application
      print("Creating new copy from asset");

      // Make sure the parent directory exists
      try {
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
      } catch (_) {}

      // Copy from asset
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "example.db"));
      List<int> bytes =
          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

      // Write and flush the bytes written
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    } else {
      print("Opening existing database");
    }
    // open the database
    return await openDatabase(path);
  }

  Future<List<Countries>> getCountries() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.query('Country', orderBy: 'countryId');
    return result.map((data) => Countries.fromMap(data)).toList();
  }
```

Here is my `main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:city_travel_guide/data/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:city_travel_guide/model/Country.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'widgets/maindrawer.dart';
import 'pages/search.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'City Travel Guide',
        theme: ThemeData.dark(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: MyHome());
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreen createState() => _HomeScreen();
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<MyHome> {
  List<Countries> countries;
  final dbHelper = DbHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    dbHelper.initDb();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'City Travel Guide',
            style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline6,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchScreen()),
                  );
                }),
            IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert), onPressed: () {}),
          ],
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(child: MainDrawer()),
        body: buildBody(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {},
        ));
  }

  buildBody() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Countries>>(
        future: dbHelper.getCountries(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data[index].countryName));
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

How can I list items on my asset database and view it in application?

Comment: Removed android-studio tag as that tag is for problems/questions related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FutureBuilder is an asynchronous request. Always check that snapshot has data before building your list.
do:

```
buildBody() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Countries>>(
        future: dbHelper.getCountries(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length > 0) // This ensures that you have at least one or more countries available.
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data[index].countryName));
            },
          );
       else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length == 0) 
          return Center(child:Text("There are no countries available"));
        return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                        Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                  )); // This would display a loading animation before your data is ready
        });
  }
```

Comment: Okay , we got rid of exception. But, we have data in our asset database and we cannot see it :(

Answer (score 0):

Its to easy you must check if there is a data comming from the future or not before using the snapshot.data.lenght because if the snapshot.data is null(the opperation not finished yet) then lenght was calling on null so you must do it

**The correct code**

```
  buildBody() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Countries>>(
        future: dbHelper.getCountries(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if(snapshot.hasdata&&snapshot.data.runtimetype==List){
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data[index].countryName));
            },
          );
         }else{
               return Proggresindicator()//or any loading widgets
             }
        });
  }
}
```

and you can add check for any execption happens during the future